# Scroll to anchor point in an Iframe IOS

Tags: html, css, iframe, anchorpoint

I have an Iframe in which i want to scroll to a specific anchor. I've tried many solutions on stackoverflow, but none of them seem to work. The page scrolls fine in a normal browser, but won't scroll on an IOS device. This is the code:

```css
.grafieken {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden; 
  height: 350px;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="grafieken">
      <iframe src="http://www.externalsite.com/#anchor" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
```

The thing is that I don't want users to scroll in the Iframe, I just want the Iframe scroll automatically down to the anchorpoint.
This is possible on Android, but seems impossible on IOS. I really hope someone can help me.

Comment: Remove `scrolling="no"` - if it then works, then you need to remove it for the iOS users

Comment: When i remove `scrolling="no"`, users will be able to scroll inside the Iframe. That is something i don't want.

Comment: As I suggested: if removing scrolling no from iOS only you have only a few users that may scroll. It sounds anyway like you are trying to claim some external content for yourself, why not extract it on the server and have no problems showing it at all?

Comment: Well i want to show 6 graphs on my webpage from an external webpage, but I made an arrangement with the owner of the external webpage that i had to use Iframes. The graphs are all shown separately, but are all linked from the same source (only used different anchor points).

Comment: I see a lot of suggestions here: https://www.google.nl/search?q="scrolling%3Dno"+ios+iframe